# Can not understand the meaning of the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, future-tense

Plenty of students continue to be drawn to the intellectual thrill of linguistics field work.

1.is the sentence passive form?
2.does this indicate the future?

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) No, the present. The subject continues to attract plenty of students.

Comment: The future version is, "Plenty of students *will* continue to be drawn to the intellectual thrill of linguistics field work."

Answer (score 1):

The main verb is "continue" and is active.

However "continue" can take a chain of infinitive phrases

> continue [to do something]

and this infinitive part is passive: "to be drawn"

So the sentence is equivalent to a fully active

> (Something) continues to draw students to the intellectual thrill...

And it is pretty clear from the context that it is the "something" is the "intellectual thrill" itself.

This is the present tense. It states a present fact, and the tense, with the word "continue" imply that it has been true in the past and is expected to be true into the future, at least for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this sentence is passive and it indicates the present. Now a lot of student are attracted by ...

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! Please explain why your answer is correct; answers without explanation don't teach the patterns of English well and [may be deleted](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3294/18673).

Comment: Could you please rewrite the sentence so that i can understand easily

Comment: This sentence is written in passive form. And it does not indicate the future, but it indicates the present. And it means that a lot of students are attracted by the linguistic field

Comment: Could you please mention grandma like continue to be drawn which actually indicate present tense